# Cross site scripting JSP ( Use cout tag instead of out. print)

Tags: jsp, xss

Hi My JSP code look like this.

```
<span class="errortext">
<%
if(ExceptionUtil.getServiceExceptionMessage(ex).toString().indexOf("WMSYS.WM_CONCAT")>=0){
out.print("Sorry")
}
else

**out.print(ExceptionUtil.getServiceExceptionMessage(ex));**

%>
</span>
```

I need to do xss in else part  `out.print`.

Comment: The answer is in the title of your question: stop using scriptlets, and use the c:out tag of the JSTL.

Comment: @JBNizet Can u please rewrite it and show me please